# AJV's validator returns always true value

Tags: javascript, validation, ajv

I need to validate JSON files in following way:

```
const setupSchema = fs.readFileSync(schemaDir +'/setup.json');
```

and compiling:

```
const setupValidator = ajv.compile(setupSchema);
```

My issue is that line:

```
console.log( setupValidator('') );
```

Always returns `true` even as validator's parameter is empty string like above. I suppose that the way of loading is bad but... need ask smarter people than me.

Comment: I may help if you could post the JSON schema too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the quick start guide: (http://json-schema.org/)

> The JSON document being validated or described we call the instance,
>   and the document containing the description is called the schema.
>
> The most basic schema is a blank JSON object, which constrains
>   nothing, allows anything, and describes nothing:
>
> `{}`
>
> You can apply constraints on an instance by adding validation keywords
>   to the schema. For example, the “type” keyword can be used to restrict
>   an instance to an object, array, string, number, boolean, or null:
>
> `{ "type": "string" }`

This means that if your schema is either an empty object or does not use the JSON Schema vocabulary, Ajv's `compile` function will always generate a validation function that always passes:

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true});

var schema = {
    foo: 'bar',
    bar: 'baz',
    baz: 'baz'
};

var validate = ajv.compile(schema);

validate({answer: 42}); //=> true
validate('42'); //=> true
validate(42); //=> true
```

Perhaps your `setup.json` is either incorrectly loaded or isn't a schema as per the JSON Schema specification.

Comment: Yes. I forgot about: const setupSchema      = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(schemaDir +'/setup.json'));

Answer (score 1):

```
// You should specify encoding while reading the file otherwise it will return raw buffer
const setupSchema = fs.readFileSync(schemaDir +'/setup.json', "utf-8");
// setupSchema is a JSON string, so you need to parse it before passing it to compile as compile function accepts an object
const setupValidator = ajv.compile(JSON.parse(setupSchema));
console.log( setupValidator('') ) // Now, this will return false;
```

Instead of doing above, you can just simply require the json file using `require`.

```
const setupSchema = require(schemaDir +'/setup.json');
const setupValidator = ajv.compile(setupSchema);
console.log( setupValidator('') );
```